# How to get the date of all blog posts in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have added many blog posts in wordpress from the admin panel, but now i have to get date of the all inserted blog posts.
i have used the get_the_date(), but this function return me of just first blog post, not the date of other blog posts,
and i have also used the the_time(), this function also return me the time of only first blog post,
how i will be able to get date of the all blog posts?

Comment: Do you need the date for admin purposes or do you want to display them on the site? If you're just using them for admin purposes you could query the database for that.

Comment: @ale8oneboy but problem is that from the wp_post table how i will get the date for all blog posts.
is there is specific key in query to get all blog posts data?
Would u like to send a query that how i will get the date of the all blog posts/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried checking the codex for [Template Tags?](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts)